# Terraform multiple resources with the same monitoring settings

Tags: terraform

Multiple resources (S3, lambda, etc.) in AWS are created by different teams via Terraform scripts;

I’ve developed my Terraform scripts for CloudWatch monitoring, they require AWS ARN as input;

Is it possible to use my monitoring terraform scripts by each team without copying them to their repos?

Comment: It would be useful if you could show an example of your code, both the resources being deployed by teams using Terraform and your monitoring scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can let each team make use of your terraform scripts by creating them as a module. Then the teams can load them into their own scripts using the [module configuration section](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/usage.html) If you do not use git, or you have all terraform in one repository, there are other [ways to load a module](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/sources.html)

This is how we make and use a large number of modules to have a consistent setup across all teams. We have a git repository for each module like (module_cloudwatch_monitoring). There is nothing special about defining a module, you only need to have variables and outputs defined.

When a team wants to use that module, they can use the module syntax like:

```
module "cloudwatch_monitoring" {
   source = "git::http://your-git-repository-url.git?ref=latest"
   resource_arn = "${aws_s3_bucket.my_bucket.id}"
}
```

If the module was in a local path in the same repository, you could do something like:

```
module "cloudwatch_monitoring" {
   source = "../../modules/cloudwatch_monitoring"
   resource_arn = "${aws_s3_bucket.my_bucket.id}"
}
```